# Prolog Permutations

Tags: algorithm, prolog, permutation

I'm trying to get more into learning prolog as I'll be taking an AI class at school next semester. I've been able to get down the basics down and can do relation based stuff, however, I've been trying to learn permutations and combinatronics and they seem pretty straightforward, but it led me to a question that I can't figure out how to solve. Say I wanted to know the permutations of 1's and 0's with a certain condition that there must be atleast 4 1's in a row.
I have no idea where I would start to try and find a solution for this, but in the end I want the code to do something like this:

```
?- placeOnesAndZeros(9,X).
% where 9 is the length of the list/array and X is the permutations

[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
[1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0]
[0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0]
[0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0]
[0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0]
[0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0]
[0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1]
[1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1]
[1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0]
[0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0]
[0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0]
[0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0]
[0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1]
[1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0]
[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0]
[0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0]
[0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1]
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0]
[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0]
[0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0]
[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
```

Thank you in advance!

EDIT CODE:

```
printList([ ]).
printList([H|T]) :- print(H), nl, printList(T).

eval([],_).
eval([H|T],[1,0]):-member(H,[1,0]),eval(T,[1,0]).

placeOnesAndZeros(N, L):-length(L,N), eval(L,[1,0]).
```

Comment: `[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]` doesn't have four 1's in a row. In addition, it appears your condition is stronger than "it must have four 1's in a row", but that any time it has a 1, that 1 must be part of 4 or more contiguous 1's.

Comment: My bad on that, I was trying to type what the code *would* do since I'm kind of lost on how to do it, but your condition is a more accurate statement of what I wanted.

Comment: If you know any Prolog at all and how to manipulate lists, then you'll need to try some things. If you're not familiar with that, then you should read up on them and try a tutorial. When someone asks an open-ended question like this where they need to write code to perform a certain task and they "don't know where to start", then those being asked help of don't know whether you just need a language tutorial or what. So it's too broad of a question. Normally, on this site, it's expected that you make some attempts and show some code indicating where you're more specifically stuck.

Comment: And in either description, `[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]` is still not a valid solution. ;)

Comment: A permutation is a `Transposition` , permutation does not mean that you fill in ones and zeros but you  change their positions.

Comment: Is there a specific term for what I'm looking for? Because I've been trying to mess with permutations to no avail. I edited my code into the OP.

Comment: @LuaiGhunim permutations can be generated via insertion. For example, see this [answer for even and odd permutations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5571558/counting-permutations-of-a-list-in-prolog#answer-19360513).

Comment: @lurker Well, i don't agree because with insertion you changing the whole space and then it's not permutation but insertion and permuation(two different things) btw for even and odd permuation you can control the sign of determinant, easy

Comment: @LuaiGhunim my point is that the insertion can be a construction process for the permutation and describes a relationship between a permutation of n items and permutation of n-1 items. Certainly there are other methods. You can disagree, but it's all right there in the Q&A that I linked. Certainly a permutation is not an insertion, but the relationship could prove useful in some permutation problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Generate and test* it's the name of the basic technique used to search a solution space. In Prolog, it's practically built in. Just provide a filter discarding what is not required:

```
?- placeOnesAndZeros(9,L),once(append(_,[1,1,1,1|_],L)).
```

once/1 is required, otherwise append/3 could succeed multiple times.
To check the correctness of the approach, here is how to count how many solutions we get:

```
?- aggregate(count,L^H^T^(placeOnesAndZeros(9,L),once(append(H,[1,1,1,1|T],L))),C).
C = 111.
```

The quantification on variables L,H,T (these last 2 being introduced only to aggregate) can be avoided using [aggregate_all](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=aggregate_all/3):

```
?- aggregate_all(count,(placeOnesAndZeros(9,L),once(append(_,[1,1,1,1|_],L))),C).
C = 111.
```

*edit*

As @lurker noted, my filter isn't correct. Try instead

```
atLeastFourOnes(L) :- memberchk(1,L), atLeastFourOnes_(L).

atLeastFourOnes_([]).
atLeastFourOnes_([0|L]) :- atLeastFourOnes_(L).
atLeastFourOnes_([1,1,1,1|L]) :- stripOnes(L,R), atLeastFourOnes_(R).
```

that yields

```
?- placeOnesAndZeros(9,L),atLeastFourOnes(L).
L = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] ;
L = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0] ;
L = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0] ;
...

?- aggregate(count,L^(placeOnesAndZeros(9,L),atLeastFourOnes(L)),C).
C = 22.
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This actually helped out a ton and you and lurker explained it well enough for me to understand, so again thanks :D